# How do I close source file after copying?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to close the original source file after copying it to my Dashboard. How do I do it?

```
Sub Load_Loan()
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant  
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="*.XLS, *CSV", Title:="Select Tape")

    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks(" Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets(Workbooks(" Dashboard.xlsm").Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Workbooks(" Dashboard.xlsm").Activate
```

I had to debug

Comment: Instead of `Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath` you should `Dim sourceWB as Workbook` and `Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(filename:=fNameAndPath)`. Then, at the end of your procedure you can simply do `sourceWB.Close`

Answer (score 1):

it's safer if you use object variable:

```
dim wb as workbook
set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fNameAndPath)
'do your stuff
wb.close
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more precise in which workbook your worksheets are and avoid using `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveWorkbook` wherever possible.

```
Public Sub Load_Loan()
    Dim fNameAndPath As Variant  
    fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="*.XLS, *CSV", Title:="Select Tape")

    If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub

    Dim WbSource As Workbook  'reference the opened workbook in a variable that we can use later to access/close it
    Set WbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fNameAndPath)

    Dim WbDestination As Workbook
    Set WbDestination = ThisWorkbook  'or if it is not the workbook this code is in then Workbooks("Dashboard.xlsm")

    'specify a worksheet in the source workbook
    WbSource.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=WbDestination WbDestination.Sheets(WbDestination.Sheets.Count)
    WbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False   'close and don't save
End Sub
```